# Check If a FileUpload hase done Nothing in Client Side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

As you know I can click on a FileUpload Button to see a Open File dialog, but I can choose nothing and simply close or cancel it. I need to find this event and do something withing this. For example if FileUpload is fired and user does not select any file then I hide a button.

Here is a function which will call when you select on a input file button and it will make a button invisible if you have canceled selecting a file.

```
        function CancelCheck(element) {
        var file = elemeny.files[0];
        if (file == undefined)
            document.getElementbyId("Btn1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
```

AND HERE is my input file control:

```
<input id="Upload1" type="file" name="file" onchange="javascript:CancelCheck(this)" runat="server" accept=".txt" />
```

It will work if you have previously selected a file ( I mean input file contains a file), But if you are clicking on int for the first time and canceling it, it won't work.

Hope I'm Clear Enough.

Comment: please post some of your html code where the fileupload control is, so we can make a suggestion.

Comment: @celerno Thank you, I have posted some html and javascript codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event but there is some **dirty** solution. However I wouldn't recommend it unless really necessary.

So we should consider what happens when the "Cancel" button is clicked - the browser and the HTML document are focused. To handle "dialog cancel event" we can attach an event handler for `onfocus` event on the HTML body (for example). Once this handler is reached, we must remove it and then we can check if the value of the file uploader is empty.

Here is sample example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload')

fileUpload.addEventListener('click', onUploadClick);

function onUploadClick() {
    document.body.addEventListener('focus', onBodyFocus, true);
}

function onBodyFocus() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!fileUpload.value || !fileUpload.value.length) 
        {
            alert('cancelled');
        }
    }, 100);

    document.body.removeEventListener('focus', onBodyFocus);
}
```

[**Click for JsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lqrzna2/)

Comment: Thank you, but I have more than 10 upload buttons, How Can I handle them then?

Comment: You should use some class for upload buttons and a temporary variable for storing the selected upload button - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lqrzna2/1/)

Comment: Is there any way to check if user has clicked on upload button?

Comment: Yes, in my example this is done through class `fileUpload`. However you can check if the target of the event is instance of `HTMLInputElement` and if its type is `file`. Example: `var isUploadBtn = e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type === 'file'`.